# Moving site to new SSP - what are the implications?

Tags: 2007, shared-service-provider

We have a MOSS 2007 installation which I try to do a little as possible with as every time we have an issue with it we are completely dumbfounded, but hey this is my job :)

We have a situation where the searchDB for our current default Shared Services Provider has reached 360GB, after reading loads of articles and trying to shrink files, databases and reset the crawl index I believe I'm left with having to migration our sharepoint site onto a new SSP - then drop the old one/dbs to regain some space.

I have created a new SSP and done a user import without too much trouble but now I'm at the point where I have to move the site from one SharedServices instance to another, my question is what are the implications of doing this operation? I've gone through all the options for the current SSP and I do not believe it has any *special* configuration. I'd appreciate any help or words of wisdom - thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I've moved a site to a new SSP some years ago and I found that I did not give any serious problems if you have aware of the following.

- All search index will be lost and will have to be reindex on the new SSP
- Check if you have custom properties on profile import
- Check if you have any metadata properites on search settings
- Check that all seach scopes have been moved to the new SSP
- If you are using audience make sure they are copied to new SSP (note that copied audience gets new guid and that can create problems)
- Filetype in search settings (pdf is not included as standart in new SSP)

Hope this helps a little in moving to the new SSP.

Comment: Fantastic thank you, checked the settings of the new SSP against the current one and everything was pretty much default apart from the user profile import. Moved the site and have yet to see any issues :)